# What should I put in the tp_name field when defining a type in a Python extension?

Tags: python

I am developing an interface so that Python programs can call into an existing C++ library.  If I understand correctly, such an interface (and the C++ library) should be imported as a module, say `abc`.  The types in the interface are defined as static variables on the C++ side of the interface, and registered with Python using the following sequence:

```
void PythonRegistrationData::RegisterType(PyObject* module, PyTypeObject* type)
{
    if (type->ob_refcnt < 2)
    {
        if (type->tp_base != NULL)
            RegisterType(module, type->tp_base);
        Py_INCREF(type);
        if (PyType_Ready(type) != 0)
            throw GPython::DummyError();
        PyModule_AddObject(module, type->tp_name, as<PyObject>(type));
    }
}
```

(The recursion is to ensure that base classes are registered before the derived class.  The module has been created earlier.)  According to the [C-API docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html), “For statically allocated type objects, the tp_name field should contain a dot.”; for this reason, I initialize `tp_name` with `"abc.MyType"`.  When I do this, after loading the module, I get `'module' object has no attribute 'MyType'` when I try to use the type (e.g. `x = abc.MyType()`, having done `import abc` before).  If I use just `"MyType"`, it seems to work, but this seems to contradict both the official documentation and the examples in the tutorial.

So what is the exact meaning of the `tp_name` field, and what should it really contain?  And what is the effect of my not putting the module name in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By doing

```
PyModule_AddObject(module, type->tp_name, as<PyObject>(type));
```

you are adding the type to the module (which means setting an attribute) using "abc.MyType" as the *attribute* name. Which means you would need to access it using `getattr(abc, 'abc.MyType')` if you wanted to access it on the `abc` module (you can't access attributes with dots in the name directly.) You *should* set the `tp_name` to the "qualified" name (with `abc.` in front of it), you just shouldn't use the tp_name as the attribute name.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.  I'm not interested in accessing the type through a function like `getattr` (although that should work correctly as well); I need the type to function as a type which is a member of the module, e.g. in expressions like `abc.MyType()` (to create a new instance of the type).  When I use the qualifier (`"abc.MyType"` in `tp_name`), I get an error message when I try to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the question any differently than I already have. Your problem isn't `tp_name`, your problem is the string you're passing to `PyModule_AddObject`. You're passing `"abc.MyType"` to `PyModule_AddObject`. You need to pass `"MyType"` instead. You should not pass `tp_name` directly to `PyModule_AddObject`.

Comment: That sounds like it might be the key: I'd overlooked the fact that I was passing exactly this string as the name in `PyModule_AddObject` as well.

Comment: Just to confirm.  I added code to trim the module name part in the loop, and it now works as expected.  Thanks.